# To what degree does Polymorph Any Object change the subject?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, polymorph

*Alter self* changes just **the form**, and lists the ways in which the change is limited:

> must be the same creature type, must be within one size category, retain your own ability scores, **Su**pernatural and **Ex**traordinary features of the form do not change, you keep the Su/Ex features resulting from class.

*Polymorph*, performs like *alter self*, but then explains how it is different, in that it changes the actual creature into another form of creature, not just in form but actually.  It does not gain the extraordinary special qualities of its new form, such as regeneration.

> change into another form of living creature; the new creature must be of the types listed; size restriction is **again** listed, as is its composition (no incorporeal or gaseous forms); physical stats (str,dex,con) change but not psychological (int/wis/cha); and it gains all special attacks but not qualities of its new forms. (ie. breath weapon vs. regeneration)

*The form of* is very different than *another form of*.

*Polymorph any object* (PAO) says that it performs like *polymorph*, except that it changes one object or creature into another.  I read it to mean that it changes from this into that, period.  Each spell iteration refers to its former to avoid redundancy of explanations.  *Polymorph* doesn't have to reiterate that it takes on the physical qualities, it says that it in *alter self*.  PAO doesn't have to say that it changes the creature's type, it says that already in *polymorph*, and it doesn't need to list the physical qualities, again that's already explained.  *Polymorph* goes on to explain the ways in which the change is restricted, but PAO does not.

If a human is changed into a troll with *polymorph*, it does **not** gain the regeneration.

Does a human gain the regeneration capability when polymorphed into a troll with *polymorph any object*?

This question was put forth by another person for Pathfinder, and was answered to mean that the change is total.
[pathfinder 1e - Confused about Polymorph any object](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95546/confused-about-polymorph-any-object?rq=1)

In this edition, however, is the only difference between the level **4** spell *polymorph*, and the level **8** spell *polymorph any object* that the latter can target objects?  Or does it change the target entirely?

Answer (score 3):

A wizard who casts the 8th-level Sor/Wiz spell [***polymorph any object***](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#polymorph-any-object) [trans] (*Player's Handbook* 263) so as to change a rock into a [**troll**](http://dndsrd.net/monstersTtoZ.html#troll) (*Monster Manual* 247–8) doesn't change that rock into a troll that possesses the extraordinary ability regeneration because the subject of the 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell [***polymorph***](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#polymorph) [trans] (*PH* 263) "does not gain the extraordinary special qualities possessed by the new form."

Likewise, a wizard who casts the *polymorph any object* spell on a rock can't change that rock into a **dread** [**wraith**](http://dndsrd.net/monstersTtoZ.html#wraith) (*MM* 257–8) because from the *polymorph* spell the *polymorph any object* spell inherited *all of* that it can't result in a creature possesses the undead type *and* that it "can’t cause a subject… to assume an incorporeal… form," *and* that "the assumed form [has] a maximum of 15 H[it] D[ice]…." (A dread wraith has 16 HD.)

The *polymorph any object* spell doesn't remove the *polymorph* spell's restrictions by saying that "it changes one object or creature into another" then not offering details. Those details aren't offered because those details are included with the *polymorph* spell, which the *polymorph any object* spell functions as except in the ways that the *polymorph any object* spell itself *does* detail.

## Getting from there to here

The 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell ***alter self*** [trans] (*Player's Handbook* 197), in part, says, "You assume the form of a creature of the same type as your normal form."

The 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell ***polymorph*** [trans] (*PH* 263), in part, says, "This spell functions like *alter self*, except that you change the willing subject into another form of living creature." Hence, instead of only being able to affect the caster like the *alter self* spell, the *polymorph* spell can affect any willing subject. (The spell's header material also makes it so that the subject must be living—most constructs, deathless, and undead can't be affected by a *polymorph* spell.)

The 8th-level Sor/Wiz spell ***polymorph any object*** [trans] (*PH* 263), in part, says, "This spell functions like *polymorph*, except that it changes one object or creature into another." Hence, instead of only being able to affect willing and living creatures like the *polymorph* spell, the *polymorph any object* spell can affect any creature or object. (The spell's header material also makes it so that an object must be nonmagical and no more than 100 cu. ft. per level. Because it's an effect mandating a Fortitude saving throw that also affects objects, constructs, deathless, and undead can be affected by the *polymorph any object* spell.)

The *polymorph any object* spell is still like the *polymorph* spell except where it says that it is not, and *where* it is not like the *polymorph* spell is detailed immediately after it says, "This spell functions like *polymorph*, except that it changes one object or creature into another."

That is, the *polymorph any object* then goes on to explain that the spell's duration is not the *polymorph* spell's 1 min/level but, instead, determined arbitrarily by the DM. (To what kingdom does a fire elemental belong?) Also, "[u]nlike *polymorph*, *polymorph any object* does grant the creature the Intelligence score of its new form." Further, because the *polymorph any object* spell can, essentially, create life, it adds, "If the original form didn’t have a Wisdom or Charisma score, it gains those scores as appropriate for the new form." Finally, it goes on for a few paragraphs about how the spell interacts with objects (because the *polymorph* spell doesn't interact with objects at all). And, by the way, it says that a caster can employ a *polymorph any object* spell so that it duplicates a handful of other spells. And, in case you missed it, the header material gives the *polymorph any object* spell a range of close. (The *polymorph* spell's range is touch.)

These are the extent of the *polymorph any object* spell's differences from the *polymorph* spell. The *polymorph any object* spell makes no other modifications to the *polymorph* spell's rules, like what is gained or lost when the new form is a creature.

Saying that ***Because the* polymorph *spell goes on to explain the ways in which the change is still restricted but the* polymorph any object *spell does not explain the ways in which* it *is restricted means that the* polymorph any object *spell is no longer bound by the limits of the* polymorph *spell*** may be a case of the reader bringing the reader's own expectations to the text: That is, because the *polymorph* spell removed some restrictions from the *alter self* spell, so must the *polymorph any object* spell also remove some restrictions of the *polymorph* spell.

But the *polymorph any object* spell, in fact, *does* remove some restrictions of the *polymorph* spell. However, instead of, for example, granting the new form a creature's extraordinary and supernatural abilities (which, to be clear, the *polymorph any object* spell does *not* grant, and it would be a *very* big deal if it did), the changes wrought to the *polymorph* spell by the *polymorph any object* spell are in the latter spell's targeting (it's pitch: "Now you can affect nonmagical objects plus deathless, undead, and constructs—but, no, still not plants"), range, and duration ("You figure it out"), and that the result can be *either* a creature *or* an object ("Just don't try to make bank and something something special materials something").

Nonetheless, the *polymorph any object* spell's mechanics—the details of what creatures can result from it and what creatures keep from their original forms while in their new forms and what creatures gain and lose due to their new forms—remain as per the *polymorph* spell because the *polymorph any object* spell does not say that it modifies those mechanics of the earlier spell—and because it says that other than exceptions that it goes on to note that the *polymorph any object* spell "functions like *polymorph*."

> #### An Aside: Consider, in context, also *shapechange*
>
> The 9th-level Sor/Wiz spell [***shapechange***](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#shapechange) [trans] (*PH* 277–8), in part, says, "This spell functions like *polymorph*, except that it enables you to assume the form of any single nonunique creature (of any type) from Fine to Colossal size." It goes on to—in addition to other changes to the earlier spell—increase the HD limit imposed by the *polymorph* spell (up to 25 HD), allow gaseous and incorporeal forms, grant the subject the new form's extraordinary abilities, and grant the subject the new form's supernatural abilities while removing the subject's own. (These aren't normally lost when the subject of a *polymorph* spell.) The *polymorph any object* spell lacks completely this kind of text, and it's this kind of text—that makes specific modifications to the earlier spell—that's necessary to modify or remove the restrictions imposed by having the *polymorph any object* spell function as the *polymorph* spell.
>
> An expansive reading of the *polymorph any object* spell's opening description—for example, "'This spell functions like *polymorph*, except that it changes one object or creature into another" to every extent with no limits'—empowers the *polymorph any object* spell well beyond the higher-level *shapechange* spell.

### "Why is this an 8th-level spell?"

I can't know why the designers opted to make the *polymorph any object* spell an 8th-level spell. However, I've DMed for PCs that wielded the *polymorph any object* spell, and I can vouch for its versatility and problem-solving acumen. In practice, the *polymorph any object* spell like the 9th-level Sor/Wiz spell [***wish***](http://dndsrd.net/spellsTtoZ.html#wish) [univ] (*PH* 302–3) except that the results are mundane, and, in some ways, it's more fun. (It requires material components found in any spell component pouch, and it costs no XP to cast, so it can be cast capriciously and whimsically.) No, the *polymorph any object* spell won't grant the resultant creature a typical form's spell-like or supernatural abilities nor many of its extraordinary abilities, but it can change a pebble into a living creature (even a plant!) with up to 15 [Hit](http://dndsrd.net/monstersG.html#fire-giant) [Dice](http://dndsrd.net/monstersDtoDe.html#delver), change the party fighter into a **firbolg** (*Monster Manual II* 101–2) permanently (i.e. until dispelled), and turn a [**vampire**](http://dndsrd.net/monstersTtoZ.html#vampire) (*MM* 250–3) into a [rowboat](http://dndsrd.net/goodsAndServices.html#rowboat) (but not into a barghest, iron golem, mummy, treant, or adamantine sword). That's really not nothing.

Sure, this means that the *polymorph any object* spell pretty much only results in boring creatures and objects, but, y'know, *most of the universe is boring*, so, in that sense, the *polymorph any object* spell still commands my respect as a DM. If, in your campaigns, you find that the *polymorph any object* spell is underperforming compared to other 8th-level spells, I'd humbly suggest lowering the spell of level of the *polymorph any object* spell rather than increasing its power: even bound as it is to the *polymorph* spell, I'd imagine it'd quickly become, for example, an extremely popular *6th*-level spell.

Comment: (Actually, *PAO* can turn a vampire into a treant (but, for a variety of reasons, *not* a treant into a vampire); I'll make this minor edit when there's more to add.)

Comment: So you're saying that a vampire turned into a boat still retains its Fast Healing 5.
And you're saying the only difference is that it can affect creatures "and objects".

Comment: @smuckenfart I can't say for certain how a particular DM would rule, but *PAO* inherits from just *P* some of *alter self*'s limits, and *AS* says that "you lose any [extraordinary abilities] from your normal form that are not derived from class levels (such as a dragon’s frightful presence ability)," this would include, I think, by extension, the vampire's extraordinary ability fast healing. However, I will readily admit that guidelines for changing creatures and objects into objects and creatures, respectively, is woefully underdetailed by the game generally and not just by *PAO.*

Comment: RE: "[T]he only difference is that it [*PAO*] can affect creatures 'and objects.'" That—and it has range, a potentially much longer duration (up to permanent), expands the scope of possible targets to include many nonliving creatures (but not plants), and expands *to a whole 'nother level* the scope of possible results. You want more from an 8th-level spell than permanently changing a PC to Large and setting his Str to 36? `:-)`

Comment: I thank you for your in depth discussion, this is insightful and challenging. Love it! So, by your own words here, whatever a Simulacrum was, the traits of that form would be lost when polymorphed into something else. The inability to be healed and inability to gain in power, traits of being a simulacrum, whether it is normal or extraordinary, are gone. yes? It's not supernatural or spell-like, or those restrictions would fade in an antimagic field as described by the monster manual glossary. :) Consider that, my friend, as you revisit the Simulacrum conversation.

Comment: Happy to oblige. If I can be so bold, the part that might be missing from your assessment of simulacrum is the *polymorph* spell line's lack of interaction with [*natural abilities*](http://dndsrd.net/specialAbilities.html#natural-abilities). The *polymorph* line doesn't interact with natural abilities, and since they aren't mentioned as being lost by *polymorph et al.*, they are kept regardless of form. If forced, I'd likely classify being a simulacrum as a natural ability. (The term *trait* is typically used in conjunction with race, type, and subtype—none of which apply to a simulacrum.)

Comment: Traits are associated with constructs, a sim is a construct.  Therefore traits are not limited to race/type and subtype.  A sim is an artificial being, which is a construct trait.  That artificial being has its traits defined by the spell definition and the creature type the sim was duplicated from.  I don't see evidence suggesting it is otherwise.  As for where polymorph interacts with natural abilities?  Can you give an example of a natural ability that polymorph/alter self doesn't interact with?

Comment: Is there evidence to suggest that the spell's description of a simulacrum's traits aren't due to its physical nature, that of being a simulacrum?  If you can point me to it, I'll definitely reassess my viewpoint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143178/discussion-between-hey-i-can-chan-and-smuckenfart).